# 403 error returned from python get requests, but auth works in postman?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, get

I'm trying to return a GET request from an API using HTTPBasicAuth.

I've tested the following in Postman, and received the correct response

```
URL:"https://someapi.data.io"
username:"username"
password:"password"
```

And this returns me the data I expect, and all is well.

When I've tried this in python however, I get kicked back a `403 error`, alongside a

```
""error_type":"ACCESS DENIED","message":"Please confirm api-key, api-secret, and permission is correct."
```

Below is my code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

URL = 'https://someapi.data.io'
authBasic=HTTPBasicAuth(username='username', password='password')
r = requests.get(URL, auth = authBasic)
print(r)
```

I honestly can't tell why this isn't working since the same username and password passes in Postman using HTTPBasicAuth

Comment: Show your cURL request from Postman.

Comment: Please share some details on the Postman request (export it to cURL as @aaron) is suggesting. Do you have any headers like `api-key`, `api-secret` in Postman? If so, you have to add it to your code in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not conveyed all the required parameters. And postman is doing this automatically for you.

To be able to use in python requests just specify all the required parameters.

```
headers = {
    'Host': 'sub.example.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Chrome v22.2 Linux Ubuntu',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}
url = 'https://sub.example.com'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: HTTPBasicAuth() adds the needed extra headers to the request

Answer (score 2):

It could be due to the fact that the user-agent is not defined

try the following:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

URL = 'https://someapi.data.io'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36'}
authBasic=HTTPBasicAuth(username='username', password='password')
r = requests.get(URL, auth = authBasic, headers=headers)
print(r)
```